# Cross-Compile of Boost for GCC ARM (Linux) from Windows building .o but not .a

Tags: c++, linux, boost, arm, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling Boost for a Linux distro on an ARM board. I'm using windows with Boost 1.47.

My project-config.jam contains the following:

> ```
> import option ; 
>
> using gcc : arm : "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeSourcery/Sourcery
> ```
>
> G++ Lite/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++" ;
>
> ```
> option.set keep-going : false ;
> ```

And I'm building with the command:

> bjam toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux

Whilst .o objects are building just fine, .a builds are failing usually with something like:

> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin"
> ```
>
> "bin.v2\libs\wav
>   e\build\gcc-arm\release\link-static\target-os-linux\threading-multi\libboost_wav
>   e-gcc-mt-1_47.a"
>
> ...failed gcc.archive
>   bin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc-arm\release\link-static\target-
>   os-linux\threading-multi\libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_47.a... ...skipped
>   libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_47.a for lack of libboost_wav
>   e-gcc-mt-1_47.a... ...failed updating 23 targets... ...skipped 28
>   targets... ...updated 641 targets...

I am also getting quote a few of the following error messages:

> '"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin"' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Any ideas guys?

Many thanks

Comment: did any of the solutions provided in the answers work for you? if yes, accept the answer that worked for you so others ending here will know that your problem was rectified.

Answer (score 2):

I just have:

```
import option ; 

using gcc : arm : arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++.exe ; 

option.set keep-going : false ;
```

And the compiler in the path.  Works for me.  Perhaps '\' vs '/' in your case.

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html

EDIT: To add the

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin

directory to your path follow the instructions here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: [ask] If I remove the full path I receive the following error: where would I have to define this compiler variable?

`C:/Users/Ali/Documents/RaspberryPi/Libs/boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/tools\gcc.ja
m:77: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: provided command 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++' not found
error: initialized from project-config.jam:3`

Comment: Add the path to the compiler binary into your Windows path.  In the System control panel under Advanced System Options, Enviornment Variables, System Variables, Path.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, it was caused by the spaces within the path which aren't properly handled by boost.build. Either switch to boost 1.48.0, or move CS into a path without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The error for C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\bin sounds like a variable for the name of the compiler is missing.

Comment: How would I go about adding this variable?